# Hotkey script to open url in browser?

Tags: shortcut-keys

How could I best write a hotkey script that opens an url in the webbrowser (firefox)?

Example:

```
ALT+G = www.google.de
ALT+W = www.wikipedia.de
```

Or would I have to use some kind of existing software therefore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this purpose, you can crate **Custom shortcut**:

1. Go to **System Settings** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts** (tab) → **Custom Shortcuts** (section) → Add new <kbd>+</kbd>.

[image]

2. In the *Custom shortcut* window type:

   - *Name*: `Google`
   - *Command*:

     - for **FireFox**: `firefox www.google.de`
     - for **Chromium**: `chromium-browser www.google.de`
   - Click on *<kbd>Apply</kbd>*
3. Click on *Disabled*:

[image]

4. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to assign the desired shortcut:

[image]