# Shell script won't run some command when run from GUI

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gui

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh --
oathtool -b --totp XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | xclip -sel clip
echo "OTP Copied!"
sleep 2
```

The `oathtool` runs when I go to terminal and type something like `./VIP` or `sh ./VIP`.
However when I double click the sh file and choose Run in terminal, only the `echo` and `sleep` command executes, the `oathtool` does nothing.

Comment: try using absolute paths...

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte, the path is not the troublemaker here, both `oathtool` and `xclip` are located in `/usr/bin/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have checked the option **Ask each time** for the **Executable Text File** in the [Nautilus Preferences](https://askubuntu.com/a/537318/566421), then you will have two options `Run in Terminal` and `Run`, when you (double) cluck on an executable by the mouse:

[image]

You need to choice `Run` to achieve what you want. This is also the default behavior if you have set **Run executable text files when they are opened** in Nautilus Preferences.

These two options `Run in Terminal` and `Run` have different behavior, but unfortunately I didn't found any additional documentation. Probably the first one creates a temporal environment that is annihilated when the terminal is closed. We can prove that by adding `exec sh` at the bottom of your script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh --
oathtool -b --totp XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | xclip -sel clip
echo "OTP Copied!"
sleep 2
exec sh
```

The command `exec sh` will replace the current shell (of your script) by a new `sh` shell, thus the terminal window will be kept open and your clipboard will be active until you are close the terminal window. Another option is to extend the `sleep` time, then your clipboard will be active while the terminal window *sleeps*.

If you are using the `Run` option or [custom shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/a/911472/566421) I would suggest you to modify your script in this way:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh --
oathtool -b --totp XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | xclip -sel clip \
&& notify-send "OTP Copied!"
```

Thus `notify-send` will send you a notification within the GUI environment only when the previous command returns **true**, which is the meaning of `&&`.

---

I've tested the described above in Ubuntu 16.04 and 19.04, there is no difference - the same behavior and the proposed solutions are working in both OS.

Comment: thank you very much! The notify-send method worked well :D